# Finding a div tag relative to a position?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I am using knockout in asp.net. I wish to reuse a partial view that is bound to a viewmodel. I.e. two usages, in each case bound to different viewmodels.

```
    <div class="col-xs-5" data-bind="with: vm1">
       @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Customers/Modals.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Shared/Views/Lookup.cshtml")
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-5" data-bind="with: vm2">
       @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Customers/Modals.cshtml")
        @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Shared/Views/Lookup.cshtml")
    </div>
```

That works in so far as to show the lookup based on correct viewmodel.

However, in the viewmodel code, a model div tag from the Modals is searched for and then shown modal. This causes problem in one of the places, as the 'modal div' found is always the same (the first, I think).

Is there a way to search for a div tag indicating that I want something relative to where I am?

BR from the backend developer :)

Comment: If you're searching for a div, you're doing Knockout wrong unless you're within a custom binding handler. You should be searching your viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a unique `id` attribute to each `div`, based on a `id` property in your view model (id or anything else):

```
<div class="col-xs-5" data-bind="with: vm1, attr:{id: vm1.id}">
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Customers/Modals.cshtml")
    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Shared/Views/Lookup.cshtml")
</div>

<div class="col-xs-5" data-bind="with: vm2, attr:{id: vm2.id}">
   @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Customers/Modals.cshtml")
    @Html.Partial("~/Areas/Shared/Views/Lookup.cshtml")
</div>
```

Then in you view model:

```
var ViewModel = function(data) {
    var self = this;

    // Generate a random string, you might want to use your own method there
    this.id = ko.observable( Math.random().toString(36).substring(7) );

    // Div selection:
    self.findDiv = function() {
        // or $('#'+self.id()) if using JQuery
        return document.getElementById(self.id());
    }
}
```